# How can I batch a Tensorflow Dataset which has labels of varying lengths?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a CNN model to recognise handwritten text by training it on the IAM dataset. I have padded the images to shape (150, 150, 3) and the labels are encoded by the following:

```
# ASCII Character list for encoding
characterList = [c for c in '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^{|}~']

# Mapping characters to integers
char_to_num = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=characterList, mask_token=None
)

# Mapping integers back to original characters
num_to_char = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True
)
```

The issue I have is that each input image corresponds to a label of varying length. For Example

- "The" = [56, 18, 15]
- "quick" = [27, 31, 19, 13, 21]
- ...

And for this reason I cannot batch the dataset by doing

```
train_df = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.stack(df.X.values), df.y.values))
train_ds = train_ds.batch(batch_size)
```

which returns the error "Cannot batch tensors with different shapes". How can I batch the tf.Data.dataset object?

df.X = series of np.ndarray of shape (150,150,3)
df.y = series of np.array of varaible lengths as discussed above.

Comment: Like in any other NLP task you have to calculate the number of unique characters in the vocabulary and that should be the last dimension of your tensors for each word.

Comment: You can work with [RaggedTensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor).

Comment: @Priya So I pad the labels with 0s for example, and then when I calculate the ctc loss, I calculate the length without the padding?

Comment: @Frightera I've tried to use ragged tensors but Im unable to train the network as I cannot compute the ctc loss with them.